# How do I validate an image file selection on php?

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a file input selection as follows in a form which I send data from using the POST Method.

```
<input type="file" name="inputFile">
```

I would like to validate that the user has chosen a file and would like to check whether the file is an image file (png,jpg)

I am also getting stuck because a line in my code is generating an error. Why?

> 'Array key 'inputFile' is undefined'

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $file = $_FILES['inputFile']; //THIS LINE IS GENERATING AN ERROR
}
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php, https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php . Look at the examples and documentation here and make sure you've followed the steps and included what you need. For example, did you make sure to put `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form?

Comment: You are right. I forgot to include the enctype which was the reason why the key wasn't being passed to the $_FILES global. Thank you. If you want to post it as an answer and maybe improvise on the validation part I would be happy to mark it as solution.

Comment: Not really much need. It's almost certainly a duplicate of many previous questions, neither the enctype thing or how to validate an image are new knowledge or problems, you should be able to google existing examples pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

see : https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

```
foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
    // basename() may prevent filesystem traversal attacks;
    // further validation/sanitation of the filename may be appropriate
    $name = basename($_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key]);
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "data/$name");
}
```

}

see also:
[Undefined Array Key error when uploading image on php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65915323/undefined-array-key-error-when-uploading-image-on-php)

it would appear you are looking for $_FILES["inputFile"]["name"] - goodluck

Answer (score -2):

You can use something like:

```
<input type="file" name="myImage" accept="image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg" />
```

And specify the formats you want without PHP

Comment: server-side validation should always be added as well, for security. Client-side validation adds usability but it's trivial to bypass. It's fine to suggest it, but don't also suggest that OP can forget about validating it in the PHP, that creates a security hole.

Comment: As the person above said, I'm looking for a way to do the validation on the server. But thank you anyways.